# При рисовании линий на Path пропускаются пиксели

Tags: android, path

я рисую на Path линию следующим образом:

```
 path.moveTo(p[p.size - 2].x.toFloat(),p[p.size - 2].y.toFloat())
    path.lineTo(p[p.size - 1].x.toFloat(),p[p.size - 1].y.toFloat())
```

то-есть я беру из массива точки и по ним рисую линию, после чего рисую свой Path на Bitmap c помощью следющего Paint:

```
private var paint = Paint().apply {
    color = clr
    strokeWidth = 1f
    style = Paint.Style.STROKE
}
```

проблема заключается в том, что линии так сказать обрываются, и некоторых пикселей в линии не хватает, из за чего линия получается не целой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

на изображении одна линия нарисованная с помощью двух точек

вот вариант линии когда рисую с помощью canvas.drawLines():

```
for(i in 0 until pts.size){
        pts[i] = Random.nextInt(0,1024).toFloat()
    }
    canvas.drawLines(pts,paint)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это физическое устройство или эмулятор?

Comment: @Эникейщик это устроиство, андройд 6

Comment: paint.setAntiAlias(true);

Comment: @Style-7 мне нужно рисовать линии без сглаживания, поэтому этот вариант мне не подходит

Comment: используйте canvas.drawLines();

Comment: @Style-7, изначально я так и пробовал, там была та же проблема, поэтому я решил попробовать рисовать на Path, но проблема осталась

Comment: Это из-за округления float, сначала приведите массив к int потом рисуйте

Comment: @Style-7, у меня массив а котором хранятся объекты класса Point, там значения координат и есть Int

Comment: я протестировал, у меня ничего не обрывается, хотя рисует плохо (перескакивает по х на последнем пикселе). в drawLines нужно передавать по 4 точки на линию (этого не знал)

Comment: @Style-7 через canvas.drawlines тоже появляются обрывы, изображение добавил к вопросу, какую конфигурацию paint вы используете?

Comment: да по умолчанию использую, в новой картинке у вас нет "обрывов", это нормальный вид для пиксельной линии

Comment: @Style-7 обрыв есть, на линии которая по центру, там не хватает одного пикселя

Answer (score 1, accepted):

опытным путем я обнаружил что данная проблема исчезает если убрать эту строку в конфигурации пера:

```
        strokeWidth = 1f
```

Comment: я нарисовал сверху после с пером толщиной 1f - тоже самое

Comment: @Style-7 как я понял это происходит из за того что в kotlin нельзя передать переменной float значение int, из за чего значение ширины линии получается не ровно 1

Comment: нет, там в параметрах float значение